# Detecting facebook name from another website

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to detect someone's facebook name from another website if they are logged in on FB?

Comment: You have 8 questions open, but have not accepted any answers. Please go back to your previous questions and accept answers where they have helped you. You can do this by clicking on the tick icon to the left of the answer, below the vote buttons. For more information, please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible on select sites that have partnered with Facebook for what is called InstantIdentification, but every other site must provide a login option for the user to authorise the site as an app before they can access the user info.

Comment: how about if they click on a link published on FB? is it possible then to get a fb profile id or something?

Comment: Nope. But it is really easy to add a login button and have them authorise your site, which gives you access to the whole graph api of social connections, and much more depending on what permissions you ask for, especially easy with the javascript sdk: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ but also look at social plugins